# Match a word in a string and replace them with new word in a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

```
1            Payment disappear - service got disconnected
2                                       Speed and Service
3       Provider Imposed a New Usage Cap of 300GB that ...
4              Provider Network not working and no service to boot
```

I have a column like the above. How can I match word `"network"` in entire column and label that cell as `"network issue"` in new column? Similarly, `"payment"` in entire column and label as `"payment issue"` in new column?

I tried but I am getting error.

```
df["complainttypes"] = df["complainttypes"].replace({"Internet":"Internettype"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `loc` and string search:

```
df.loc[df["type"].str.contains("payment",case=False),"complainttypes"]="Payment Issue"
```

where `type` is the column where you want to search and complainttypes is the new column where you want the final data